# How to write nested Json web services in c# for windows store app

Tags: c#, json, windows, web-services, xaml

I'm working on  windows store app where i am using a web service which have parameter which are nested like this

```
userData, @"user_login",
email, @"email",password, @"password",
```

user_login key contains to key email and password with their value .I Hit the web service in the fiddler and if works i am getting the response the parameter string i used

```
{
"user_login":{"email" : "mmmmmmmm@fdhfgh.co","password" : "pass1234"}  
}
```

when i am using this parameter string in my code i am getting error of status code 400 bad request due to the parameter string .
here is my code

```
string content = string.Empty;
                System.Net.Http.HttpClient httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Date = DateTime.Now;
                var httpContent = new System.Net.Http.StringContent("{'user_login':[{'email':"mmmmmmmm@fdhfgh.co",'password':'pass1234'}}]", Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");
                var httpResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync(" http://localhost/appi/pupil/log_in", httpContent);
                content = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

help me out with your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your C# code, you're passing in an array (as denoted by the [ ]'s). It doesn't look like your were doing that in Fiddler. It also looks like the [ ]'s aren't formatted properly. I'd try just taking that out.

EDIT:

```
"{\"user_login\":{\"email\":\"mmmmmmmm@fdhfgh.com\",\"password\":\"pass1234\"}}"
```

If this is the correct signature, the above JSON would work.

EDIT 2:

var httpResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync(" `http://localhost/appi/pupil/log_in`", httpContent);

Couldn't help but notice that you had `"localhost/appi"` instead of `"localhost/api"`. That could possibly be a typo? Along with that leading space.

Comment: ya the same string can't be used in c# so i made changes to it but i think because of the change i am getting the error status code 400.

Comment: Well, the [ ]'s are almost definitely the problem. I've edited my answer

Comment: i used the string you suggested again the same error bad request status code 400..

Comment: hi Kith i have another problem related to web service the link is here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25029807/how-to-send-request-to-the-http-header-using-the-json-webservice-in-windows-store-app . I need to sent request to the http Header