# How to send request to the HTTP Header using the json webservice in windows store app

Tags: c#, json, windows, web-services

I'm working on a windows store app where I am using a web service which has parameters for downloading videos that are given below.

```
[request addValue:Token Id forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

Through log_in web services I get the access token which I have to pass as value in the  Authorization a request to the HTTP Header.

```
Token token="hgmgmhmhgm6dfgffdbfetgjhgkj4mhh8dghmge"
```

I have to send both these parameters with the web service given to me but I am unable to send them as I'm getting the error status code `404 unauthorized`.

Here is my code:

```
 System.Net.Http.HttpClient httpClient1 = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        httpClient1.DefaultRequestHeaders.Date = DateTime.Now;
        httpClient1.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization",acesstoken);
     var httpResponse1 = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://gbdfbbnbb@gfdh.co/appi/fdbfdses/3/videos");
        string vale = await httpResponse1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        string responses = vale;
```

I know my code is wrong and I need to correct it. Help me with your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
      try
      {

          String url = "https://www.example-http-request.com/json";

          var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());
          var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
          {
              new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Authorization", acesstoken)
          };
          HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(new Uri(url), new FormUrlEncodedContent(values));
          response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
          var responsesStr = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
          if (!responsesStr.Equals(""))
          {

              //http request data now capture in responseToken string.
              //you can change name as per your requirement.

              String responseOutput = responsesStr;


              //now convert/parse your json using Newtonsoft JSON library
              // Newtonsoft JSON Librar link : { http://james.newtonking.com/json }

                 //LoggingModel is a class which is the model of deserializing your json output.
                 LoggingModel array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoggingModel>(responseOutput);

                  bool isSuccess = array.IsSuccessful;

                  if (isSuccess == true)
                  {
                      //if success

                  }else{

                      //if login failed

                  }


            }else{

                  //no response in http request failed.                                    
            }  
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          //catch exceptio here
      }
}
```

Comment: for generating a json model class for deserializing or serializing, follow this link http://json2csharp.com. Input your json formated string and it will generate a model classes based on your json string.